# iptables and bridging

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, router, network-bridge

I have a very simple task but I fail constantly :-(. So here is my simple setup:

I want to build up a router with the interface `eth0` connected to the open world on the one side and two intefaces, `eth1` and `wlan0` bridged together as `br0`. This works quite well, but now I'm trying to configure `iptables`.

What works is the connection to the internet from the clients and connection (e.g. ssh) from the router to the clients. What does not work is connection between the clients in `eth1` and `wlan0`, so I guess my configuration is not quite correct ;-).

Could anyone please explain me my error?

Thanks a lot!

Here are my `iptable` rules:

```
        iptables -F
        iptables -F -t mangle
        iptables -F -t nat

        iptables -F INPUT
        iptables -F FORWARD
        iptables -F OUTPUT

        iptables -X

        iptables -P INPUT DROP
        iptables -P FORWARD DROP
        iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

        iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

        #SSH
        iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

        #HTTP(S)
        iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT

        #DNS
        iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

        #DNS
        iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 953 -j ACCEPT

        #DHCP
        iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

        iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A OUTPUT -o br0 -j ACCEPT

        #DNS
        iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53:65535 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53:65535 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

        iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

        #HTTP(S)
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT

        #DNS
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

        #NTP
        iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

        iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlan0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

        iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

And `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is set...

Comment: What is the output of `route`?  I think you need to add a route between your two subnets.

Comment: Adding `iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT` to the FORWARD chain does the trick